# scheme update a list of bullet location with location speed direction

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying updates each bullet's location based on the bullets direction and speed for a list of bullets. And returns back the updated bullet list.

I think my code works logically but scheme gives me the error code

```
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, 
but received (make-signature ...)


;; A Bullet is (make-bullet Posn Number Direction Number)
;; interpetation: represents a bullet, its current position, 
;;                its speed, its direction and its potential damage
(define-struct bullet (location speed direction damage))

;; A Direction is one of 
;; - 'Up
;; - 'Down
;; - 'Left 
;; - 'Right

;; a list of bullets(lob) is either
;; - empty 
;; - (cons bullet lob)

;; A location is Lof[location]
;; A location is a Posn

;; move-bullets: lob -> lob 
;;  takes in a list of bullets and updates each bullet's location
;;  based on the bullets direction and speed

(define (move-bullets lob)
  (cond 
     [(empty? lob) empty]
     [(cons? lob) (cons (create-new-bullet (first lob))
                        lob)]))

;; create-new-bullet: location direction speed-> location
;; takes in a list of bullets' location and create the "moved" bullet
;; base on given direction, speed

(define (create-new-bullet location dir speed)
  (cond 
    [(symbol=? 'Up dir) 
     (make-posn (posn-x location) (- (posn-y location) speed))] 
    [(symbol=? 'Down dir) 
     (make-posn (posn-x location) (+ (posn-y location) speed))]
    [(symbol=? 'Left dir)
     (make-posn (- (posn-x location) speed) (posn-y location))]
    [(symbol=? 'Right dir) 
     (make-posn (+ (posn-x location) speed) (posn-y location))]))
```

hummh. Anything goes wrong here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a *bullet* as a parameter, so you need to extract each of its components. Try this:

```
(define (create-new-bullet bullet)
  (let ((location (bullet-location bullet))
        (speed (bullet-speed bullet))
        (direction (bullet-direction bullet))
        (damage (bullet-damage bullet)))
    (cond 
      [(symbol=? 'Up direction)
       (make-bullet
        (make-posn (posn-x location) (- (posn-y location) speed))
        speed direction damage)] 
      [(symbol=? 'Down direction) 
       (make-bullet
        (make-posn (posn-x location) (+ (posn-y location) speed))
        speed direction damage)]
      [(symbol=? 'Left direction)
       (make-bullet
        (make-posn (- (posn-x location) speed) (posn-y location))
        speed direction damage)]
      [(symbol=? 'Right direction) 
       (make-bullet
        (make-posn (+ (posn-x location) speed) (posn-y location))
        speed direction damage)])))
```

Also, you forgot to advance the recursion:

```
(define (move-bullets lob)
  (cond 
    [(empty? lob) empty]
    [(cons? lob) (cons (create-new-bullet (first lob))
                       (move-bullets (rest lob)))]))
```

Comment: tests : `(move-bullets (list (make-bullet (make-posn 10 10) 4 'Up 10)))` it gives `bullet-direction: expects 1 argument, but found none` ?

Comment: There was a bug in `create-new-bullet`, copy it again and try please

Comment: oh . I think i can just change the `make-posn` to `make-bullet`.

Comment: @pnixsweet that's the way you meant it, notice that your code for `create-new-bullet` is returning the result of calling `make-posn`